# MVC/Razor DisplayFormat Not Always Working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm new to MVC and Razor, and I am having some minor formatting issues.

I have a class object, and the following properties defined:

```
public class MarginData
    {
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###,###}")]
        public decimal? MarginAmount;

        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:###,###}")]
        public decimal? Difference { get; set; }
    }
```

Then, in my cshtml view, I have this code:

```
                        <td style="text-align: right; vertical-align: middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.Difference)
                        </td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;vertical-align: middle">
                            @Html.DisplayFor(x => item.MarginAmount)
                        </td>
```

I would expect both of these columns/values to be formatted the same way, however, one is formatted as expected: 1,233,563 and the other is just numbers  (without the formatting), like 4563477398.

What am I missing? (It's the MarginAmount item that is not formatted)

Comment: I tried just adding the { get; set; } to the MarginAmount declaration, and that seemed to resolve it. I guess I am a little confused though as to why that would matter?

Comment: Without the {get;set;} it's not a property, it's a field/member.

Comment: Those attributes are not meant for Fields (no {get;set;})

Comment: thanks both. If someone wants to throw that comment into an answer, I will accept it. Thanks

Comment: nah - you figured it yourself :) we just clarified "why" :)

Comment: I wrote an answer, but you should write your own answer on how you fixed it and accept your answer since you figured it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those MVC attributes are meant to be used for property types, not fields.  Adding the `{get; set;}` changed it from a field to a property allowing the attributes to do their magic.